# Shell get specific words in a line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file

```
     tadjag:x:60697:100:Name Surname IF-3/4 2015-02-02:/export/home/tadjag:/bin/bash
        linbul:x:60698:100:Name2 Surname2 IF-3/4 2015-02-02:/export/home/linbul:/bin/bash
        sarvis:x:60699:100:Name3 Surname3 IF-3/2 2015-02-02:/export/home/sarvis:/bin/bash
        deigru:x:60701:100:Name4 Surname4 IF-3/4 2015-02-02:/export/home/deigru:/bin/bash
        tauilc:x:60702:100:Name5 Surname5 IF-3/3 2015-02-02:/export/home/tauilc:/bin/bash
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

and I want to take only Name's and Surname's if they are from `IF-3/4`. So my result should be

```
Name Surname
Name2 Surname2
Name4 Surname4
```

what I done

```
awk -F: '{print $5}' myFile
```

So my output is

```
Name Surname IF-3/4 2015-02-02
...
...
```

So is it possible to get only Name's and Surname's if they are from `IF-3/4`

Comment: I just have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk's split function to split on spaces which exists on the column 5 and again it stores the splitted values to an associate array `a`. So `a[1]` contains the first word (*Name*) and `a[2]` contains the second word (*Surname*).

```
$ awk -F: '{split($5,a,/[[:blank:]]+/); print a[1],a[2]}' file
Name Surname
Name2 Surname2
Name3 Surname3
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to also use a[3]. For example
awk -F: '{split($5,a,/[[:blank:]]+/); print a[1],a[2]}' file
if [ "$a[3]" = "IF-3/4" ];

Comment: You mean this `awk -F: '{split($5,a,/[[:blank:]]+/); print a[1],a[2],a[4]}' file` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[: ]' 'NR<2||!(NR%2){print $5,$6}' file

Name Surname
Name2 Surname2
Name4 Surname4
```